# Subset rows in data frame based on lag and lead range relative to indicated row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame where i indicates particular rows with "1" (see df1). I would like to subset the data frame including rows where i = 1 as well all 2 rows "before" (lag1 and lag2) as well as 2 rows "after" (lead1 and lead2) the row indicated by i (see example df2). Two rows are just to illustrate the question - I would also be able to use the code to subset, e.g. 4 "before" and 4 rows "after" each i = 1.

```
df1 <- data.frame(i =(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                  values = c(9,74,30,81,14,88,62,9,32,64,3,56,84,61,95,97,65,76,31,33,56,69,77,81,80))
df2 <- data.frame(i = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0),
                  values = c(9,32,64,3,56,95,97,65,76,31,33,56,69,77))
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate indices +/-2 of i and subset using these:

```
idx <- unique(c(sapply(which(df1$i == 1), function(x) (x-2):(x+2))))

# Remove index values that might be out of range.
idx <- idx[idx > 0 & idx <= nrow(df1)]

df1[idx,] 

   i values
8  0      9
9  0     32
10 1     64
11 0      3
12 0     56
15 0     95
16 0     97
17 1     65
18 0     76
19 0     31
20 0     33
21 1     56
22 0     69
23 0     77
```